# Optimizing wireless charging

Tags: battery-charging, wireless-charging, drone

I am trying to build a wireless charging system for a drone. I have a 3s Lipo battery and I would like to plug in a wireless charger transmitter into it. I will then plug the wireless receiver onto the drone such that when it lands, it begins to charge. Below is a description of the system.

[image]

However, I cannot find any wireless receiver above 10W.

I am wondering if there is any way to use multiple receivers and multiple transmitters. Or a way of optimizing the power into the drone battery.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard)) article about Qi charging says "As of 2019, the Medium Power standard currently delivers 30 to 65 W." ... how much did you want?

Comment: why step down to 5V ? it's desirable to control the wireless charging coil with 9 or 12 V rather than 5V, usually.

Comment: Anywhere from 30-65 watts would be ideal however I cannot find any commercial receiver that can handle that wattage

Comment: hm, there certainly are chips for that, and other than that, Qi is really designed for mostly needing a microcontroller with fimrware for communications, and a controller for synchronous recrtification on the receiver side. Your step down to 5 V really really makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah sorry the stepdown may not be needed. But I was overall just wondering if there are any available ways of using commercial wireless chargers and receivers somehow to transfer more power